# Luigi HiveQueryTask save results to file

Tags: python, hadoop, luigi

I am pretty inexperienced with Luigi and Python, but I'm trying to determine why the results of a Hive query are not being saved to the specified output file. What I thought was relevant was executing via query() method and defining where to save in output():

```
class deliverableweekValues(HiveQueryTask):
    tablename = luigi.Parameter(default='basetable')
    database = luigi.Parameter(default='base_database')
    #needs to return something as output, for subsequent splitting of tasks
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('weeks_for_metrics.txt')
    #this determine what weeks are available to run metrics on
    def query(self):
        tmpl = """
SELECT DISTINCT week FROM {0}.{1} ORDER BY week
    """
        qry = tmpl.format(self.database,self.tablename)
        print (qry)
        return qry

#run only the above function via line below, ***WORKS***
luigi.run(['deliverableweekValues','--local-scheduler'])
```

This does not error, it just does not save to a file called weeks_for_metrics.txt.
Luigi output:

```
DEBUG: Checking if deliverableweekValues(tablename=basetable, database=base_database) is complete
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/parameter.py:259: UserWarning: Parameter None is not of type string.
  warnings.warn("Parameter {0} is not of type string.".format(str(x)))
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   deliverableweekValues_base_database_basetable_96cd7fa3f7   has status   PENDING
INFO: Done scheduling tasks
INFO: Running Worker with 1 processes
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
DEBUG: Pending tasks: 1

SELECT DISTINCT week FROM base_database.basetable ORDER BY week

INFO: ['hive', '-f', '/tmp/tmpEaQmC4', '--hiveconf', "mapred.job.name='deliverableweekValues_base_database_basetable_96cd7fa3f7'"]
INFO: hive -f /tmp/tmpEaQmC4 --hiveconf mapred.job.name='deliverableweekValues_base_database_basetable_96cd7fa3f7'
INFO: log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.
INFO: Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/2.6.1.0-129/0/hive-log4j.properties
INFO: Query ID = jdavidson_20180326153035_c2fdf713-037f-4c79-93f6-0328fe57d208
INFO: Total jobs = 1
INFO: Launching Job 1 out of 1
INFO: Status: Running (Executing on YARN cluster with App id application_1520857775863_57954)
INFO: OK
INFO: Time taken: 30.451 seconds, Fetched: 122 row(s)
DEBUG: 1 running tasks, waiting for next task to finish
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   deliverableweekValues_base_database_basetable_96cd7fa3f7   has status   DONE
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
DEBUG: Done
DEBUG: There are no more tasks to run at this time
INFO:
===== Luigi Execution Summary =====

Scheduled 1 tasks of which:
* 1 ran successfully:
    - 1 deliverableweekValues(tablename=basetable, database=base_database)

This progress looks :) because there were no failed tasks or missing external dependencies

===== Luigi Execution Summary =====

True
```

However, despite completing without error and fetching the correct 122 rows, the file is not present in the directory.

```
ls week*
ls: cannot access week*: No such file or directory
```

## example that does write, from luigi documentation

I have successfully written to files in this way by using the following sample code, so I believe I'm missing something fairly fundamental:

```
class GenerateWords(luigi.Task):
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('words.txt')
    def run(self):
        # write a dummy list of words to output file
        words = ['apple','banana','grapefruit']
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            for word in words:
                f.write('{word}\n'.format(word=word))

class CountLetters(luigi.Task):
    def requires(self):
        return GenerateWords()
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('letter_counts.txt')
    def run(self):
        # read in file as list
        with self.input().open('r') as infile:
            words = infile.read().splitlines()
            # write each word to output file with its corresponding letter count
        with self.output().open('w') as outfile:
            for word in words:
                outfile.write(
                    '{word} | {letter_count}\n'.format(
                        word=word,
                        letter_count=len(word)
                    )
                )

#run via
luigi.run(['CountLetters','--local-scheduler'])
```

This creates the files:

```
ls w*
words.txt
ls letter*
letter_counts.txt
```

Comment: Please include the relevant error messages within your question, if you have questions please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: A friend told me I may want to use a different method, as the HiveQueryTask does not seem to provide a good way out outputting the results of a query.

Looking at the code in my original question, he stated "the output of the hive query doesn't default to whatever you return via the "output" method". This implies that I need to find where the output actually goes, and write that into the file.

Comment: Update: this better programmer also suggests it may be impossible to grab the output of the query without creating another class altogether that works with HiveQueryTask. This is obviously outside my abilities.

Alternatively, he suggested INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY in the sql/hql statement, which I will try (and later report back if its successful)

Comment: @JonathanDavidson, were you ever able to figure this out? I'm starting to use Luigi to run hive and pyspark jobs but there's surprising little examples out there